# How to set Field private boolean set true?

Tags: boolean, smali

When i set the true value but error what's  am wrong with this code

Original

".field private isPro:Z"

My set

'''.field private isPro:Z=true'''

Answer (score 1):

In smali/dalvik **"Z"** means **"boolean"**, in your case it is defining only the **type**, not the **value**:

```
.field private isPro:Z
```

Changing **"Z"** to **"true"** will not work, since **"true"** it is not a valid type.
If you want to change its value, you need to search where the variable **isPro** is used, and change/override from **0x0** (false) to **0x1** (true).

Answer (score 1):

you should **use `iput-boolean` in constructor or any method** instead of assign directly when defining field.

```
.field private isPro:Z
```

```
#assign value
const/4 v0, 0

iput-boolean v0, p0, Lcom/example/YourClassPath;->isPro:Z
```

---

btw, direct assign only works in `static` field like below

```
# not 0 not 1
.field private static isPro:Z = true
```

Comment: That is super! Thanks. Additionally for those looking for opcode reference Checkout http://pallergabor.uw.hu/androidblog/dalvik_opcodes.html It is different from Intel Syntax